# Sacar nombre de categoria, en lugar del ID - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Buenas alguien me puede ayudar, no lo estoy haciendo bien. Tengo una tabla que se llama productos, en ella un campo que se llama `marca_id` , luego tengo una tabla que se llama marcas, en la cual la relaciono por su campo `id`, esta tabla también contiene una columna que se llama nombre.

**Modelo producto**

```
class Producto extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'productos';

    public function opciones()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Opcion', 'product_id');
    }
    public function medidas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Medida', 'product_id');
    }
    public function marcas()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Marca', 'id');
    }
}
```

**Modelo Marca**

```
class Marca extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'marcas';

    public function producto()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Producto', 'marca_id');
    }
}
```

Creo que lo hago de forma correcta, un producto solo puede pertenecer a una marca por eso el `belongsTo` pero las marcas pueden tener muchos productos por eso el `hasMany`.

Bien luego en la vista imprimo un `foreach` con todos los productos, pero no se como imprimir la marca.

```
@foreach ($productos as $pro)    
        <div class="col-4 catProduct">
            <div class="col-12 bordeCajon">
                @if ($pro->novedad == 1)
                    <div class="nEntrada">NOVEDAD</div> 
                @endif

                @if ($pro->pvpAntes == null)     
                @else
                    <div class="oferta">OFERTA!</div>
                @endif   
                <div class="minHei">
                    <img src="{{ asset("{$pro->imagen}") }}" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="paddingProducto">
                    <h2>{{ $pro->marcas->nombre }}</h2>
                    <h3>{{ $pro->producto }}</h3>
                    <div class="dividerProd"></div>
                    <h4>{{ $pro->pvpAhora }} <span>€</span></h4>

                    @if ($pro->pvpAntes == null)     
                    @else
                        <div class="pvpAntes">{{ $pro->pvpAntes }} <span>€</span></div>
                    @endif 
                    <a href="{{ route('web.detalle', ['cat' => $pro->categoria, 'sub' => $pro->subcategoria, 'url' => $pro->url]) }}" class="btn btn-primary btnForm pull-right">VER PRODUCTO</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
@endforeach
```

**Intento sacarlo así:** `{{ $pro->marcas->nombre}}` pero me devuelve el error:

```
Trying to get property 'nombre' of non-object (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/camasLiteras/resources/views/index.blade.php
```

**En el controlador**

```
public $categorias, $productos, $ofertados;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->categorias = Categoria::where('estado', 1)->get();
        $this->productos = Producto::with('marcas')
                    ->latest('id')
                    ->limit(6)
                    ->whereEstado(1)
                    ->get();
        $this->ofertados = Producto::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get()->where('estado', 1)->where('inicioOferta', 1);
            
    }
```

Comment: Y la consulta cual es?

Comment: Hola @BetaM modifico la pregunta y pongo la consulta

Comment: ¿Quieres una consulta que te arroje los productos y su respectiva categoría?

Comment: Si correcto @BetaM , no lo tengo que hacer con las relaciones?? o a de ser un INNER?, bueno más que categoría es la marca del producto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno lo he resuelto así, no creo que sea incorrecto pero yo queria utilizar los modelos, pero no puedo perder más tiempo.

```
$this->productos = DB::table('productos')
                ->join('brands', 'productos.id_brand', '=', 'brands.id')
                ->select('productos.*', 'brands.nombre')
                ->latest('id')
                ->limit(6)
                ->where('productos.estado', 1)
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Para la relacion que estas intentando acceder tienes que iterar sobre otro foreach como en lo siguiente

```
    @foreach ($productos as $pro)    
      <div class="col-4 catProduct">
         <div class="col-12 bordeCajon">
                        @if ($pro->novedad == 1)
                            <div class="nEntrada">NOVEDAD</div> 
                        @endif
    
                        @if ($pro->pvpAntes == null)     
                        @else
                            <div class="oferta">OFERTA!</div>
                        @endif   
                        <div class="minHei">
                            <img src="{{ asset("{$pro->imagen}") }}" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="paddingProducto">
//Iterar sobre otro foreach
                        @foreach($pro->marcas $marca) // de esto modo
                            <h2>{{ $marca->nombre }}</h2>
                        @endforeach
                            <h3>{{ $pro->producto }}</h3>
                            <div class="dividerProd"></div>
                            <h4>{{ $pro->pvpAhora }} <span>€</span></h4>
    
                            @if ($pro->pvpAntes == null)     
                            @else
                                <div class="pvpAntes">{{ $pro->pvpAntes }} <span>€</span></div>
                            @endif 
                            <a href="{{ route('web.detalle', ['cat' => $pro->categoria, 'sub' => $pro->subcategoria, 'url' => $pro->url]) }}" class="btn btn-primary btnForm pull-right">VER PRODUCTO</a>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: Pero no entiendo por que un `foreach` si solo quiero sacar el nombre @Dohko19

Comment: mmm si tienes `"marcas" => $this->marcas` en tu controlador es porque te quieres saltar la relacion no?

Comment: no entiendo! Si hago el foreach, me muestra en el producto el nombre de las categorías en orden, no muestra el nombre de marca que le corresponde

Answer (score 0):

Si tus llaves primarias y foráneas no siguen las convenciones de nombres que Eloquent espera en los modelos, entonces deberás configurarlas de esta forma:

Modelo **Marca**

```
class Marca extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'marcas';
    public function productos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Producto::class, 'id_brand');
    }
}
```

Modelo **Producto**

```
class Producto extends Model
{
    public function marca()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Marca::class);
    }
}
```

Ahora si ya la consulta queda de esta forma:

```
$consulta = Producto::with('marca')
                    ->latest('id')
                    ->limit(6)
                    ->whereEstado(1)
                    ->get();
```

Comment: Lo prueba así @BetaM pero sin éxito: `$consulta = Producto::with('marcas')->get();` luego lo llevo a la vista con `with` `"consulta" => $consulta[0]` y lo imprimo en la vista así : `<h2>{{ $consulta->nombre }}</h2>` no me devuelve error pero no imprime nada

Comment: Vale creo que te entendi, puedo sustituir mi consulta actual de producto por esta: `$this->productos = Producto::with('marcas')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(6)->where('estado', 1)->get();` Para luego poder sacar con un `foreach` todos los productos, pero a la hora de imprimir la marca pruebo así `{{ $pro->nombre }}` pero sin éxito

Comment: De producto! es para si saber si está activo o no

Comment: Ya lo probe @BetaM , pero me devuelve error `Trying to get property 'nombre' of non-object`

Comment: Hola @BetaM , sigue sin funcionar. No puede ser tan dificil esto, algo tengo que estar haciendo mal, me devuelve el mismo error de antes

Comment: He editado la pregunta, para que veas como quedo el controlador y la vista @BetaM

Comment: Puedes ayudarme a través de chat? y te enseño más por si tengo algo mal? Puse esto así `->latest()` y me pone las marcas, pero sin sentido @BetaM

Comment: Algo no va bien, he ido probando cosas. Por ejemplo en la tabla marcas tengo 4 marcas. En el inicio tengo 6 productos cada uno con una marca. Bien lo hace lo que hemos hecho es coge el producto y le pone el nombre de la marca en el mismo orden de la tabla marcas, es decir no pone el nombre que le toca. Y como hay 6 productos pero solo 4 marcas por eso dice lo de 'nombre' of no-object'. Si desactivo dos productos no me da error pero muestra en cada producto una marca distinta, poniendo las 4 que hay. Te puede ayudar eso @BetaM a saber que pasa?? Espero que si estoy desesperado. Gracias

Comment: Hola @BetaM mira si puedes dar un vistazo a la respuesta

Comment: Ahora que lo veo puede ser que la respuesta no te sirvió por que tu llave foránea no tiene como nombre la convención que espera Eloquent, entonces dejame ver si edito la mia

Comment: Sigue pasando lo mismo, no se si tendré algo mal para que si funcione con el INNER y no con los modelos

Comment: No logro entonces ver qué ocurre, considera entonces marcar como aceptada tu respuesta